# Showing operations are well defined.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

[image]

How would I show that addition and multiplication in Q(R) are well defined?

Comment: What does "how" mean? How to get started, that is, what it is that you want to prove, precisely? Or you've gotten started but got stuck somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $[a/b],[a'/b'],[c/d],[c'/d'] \in Q(R)$ where $[a/b]=[a'/b']$ and $[c/d]=[c'/d']$.

To show that $+$ is well-defined, you want want to show: $[a/b]+[c/d] =[a'/b']+[c'/d'].$ That is, $[ad+bc/bd]=[a'd'+b'c'/b'd']$.

To show that $\cdot$ is well-defined, you want want to show: $[a/b]\cdot[c/d]=[a'/b']\cdot[c'/d']$. That is, $[ac/bd]=[a'c'/b'd']$.

Comment: Is it really that simple? I think I was overthinking this.